# How does the JVM read system properties?

Tags: java, properties, operating-system, jvm, native

I found this in the `System` class, but I want to know how this is implemented.

```
     /**
     * System properties. The following properties are guaranteed to be defined:
     * <dl>
     * <dt>java.version         <dd>Java version number
     * <dt>java.vendor          <dd>Java vendor specific string
     * <dt>java.vendor.url      <dd>Java vendor URL
     * <dt>java.home            <dd>Java installation directory
     * <dt>java.class.version   <dd>Java class version number
     * <dt>java.class.path      <dd>Java classpath
     * <dt>os.name              <dd>Operating System Name
     * <dt>os.arch              <dd>Operating System Architecture
     * <dt>os.version           <dd>Operating System Version
     * <dt>file.separator       <dd>File separator ("/" on Unix)
     * <dt>path.separator       <dd>Path separator (":" on Unix)
     * <dt>line.separator       <dd>Line separator ("\n" on Unix)
     * <dt>user.name            <dd>User account name
     * <dt>user.home            <dd>User home directory
     * <dt>user.dir             <dd>User's current working directory
     * </dl>
     */

    private static Properties props;
    private static native Properties initProperties(Properties props);
```

Since it is a native method, I assume there is a C-File, which does all the magic.
Is there a os-specific file which loads the variables via getenv() in C or is this hard coded somehow for specific platforms (regardless from os.name, os.version etc, which have to be dynamic)?

*What if the OS is a modified Linux-Kernel with an `a` as line separator or `<foo>` as path separator? How can the JVM even know where to search for these native files, if they are stored underneath `..<foo>..<foo>native<foo>amd_xyz` before even knowing the path separator?*

Is there a way to look into the implementation?

Comment: The JVM implementation is aware of the platform's path separator, so I'm not sure what your last question is about. Whoever writes the (usually C++, I believe) implementation of the JVM for the given platform (HP-UX, AIX, whatever) will deal with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the OpenJDK source. For example the file separator for Linux is defined [like this](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/hotspot/file/03e1b9fce89d/src/os/linux/vm/os_linux.inline.hpp):

```
inline const char* os::file_separator() {
  return "/"; 
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can look at all the source in the OpenJDK. Most of the source is available to your IDE from the JDK.

I think you are assuming there is more magic than there is.  For the UNIX versions the file.separator is likely to be hard coded as it suggests in the documentation.